# Quaternion has length close to zero... discarding as navigation goal, why?

Tags: navigation, move-base, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I am trying to follow a moving target with my robot through simulation, using stage and rviz. I already managed to send a goal, using actionlib, based on the target position plus an offset. It works most of the time, but I keep getting this error message:

> Quaternion has length close to zero... discarding as navigation goal

Why?? What does that mean?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28819/quaternion-has-length-close-to-zero...-discarding-as-navigation-goal,-why?/) by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4402 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the quaternions you are actually sending? Any quaternion sent should be a properly normalized one (length = 1). The default constructed quaternion geometry_msgs/Quaternion is not a valid quaternion, since it is all 0's.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-03-01**:
thanks. I was actually sending an empty message alternated with a proper one. That is why I could get the robot to move and still get the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It probably means the rotation quaternion of your goal pose is not properly normalized (e.g. the square root of the sum of squared elements is not 1). Rotation quaternions are generally expected to be normalized, as using non-normalized quaternions would lead to bugs that are hard to detect.

You'll have to check the code generating the target pose for answering the "why?" question.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-03-01**:
thanks for your input!